# Robot Framework selecting from UL ID and li class

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am unable to select any of the ul id / li class items. I do not see a method for handling this. Anyone able to get it done?

```
<ul id="game_list">
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('one');">ONE</li>
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('two');">TWO</li>
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('three');">THREE</li>
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('four');">FOUR</li>
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('five');">FIVE</li>
<li class="game_link" onclick="update_blurb('six');">SIX</li>
</ul>
```

I am attempting to select the li class links.

Comment: Are you using seleniumlibrary (Based on the old Selenium RC), or selenium2library (Based on the new Selenium WebDriver)?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. Using Web Driver (Selenium2Library)

Comment: On the second thought - _what_ exactly do you want to get? The class on the `<li>` elements? Or their text? Ore something else? What is your desired output?

Comment: My attempt is to 'click' on that line item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what is the problem. The right method to click on things is [`Click Element`](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Click%20Element). You can select any of the `<li>` elements by a CSS selector or an XPath expression ([documentation, see "Locating elements"](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Introduction)).

For example:

```
Click Element | css=#game_list > li:nth-child(3)
```

clicks the third `<li>` element.

Or by text:

```
Click Element | xpath=id('game_list')/li[text()='THREE']
```

selects the `<li>` element whose text is "THREE".

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

I create my own element id and click that new id.

Example:

```
Assign Id To Element  xpath=//li[@onclick="update_blurb('one');"]  one
Click Element  one
```

Thanks for checking it out, Slanec.

Comment: Assigning ID to an element is intended for repeated interaction with the same element. E.g. if you have an element that is found via some horribly hard XPath that takes a few seconds to run and you want to perform several actions on it, it's good to assign an id to the element (since id lookup is instant) so that you don't have to slowly search for it every time.